# closing a code tag in Razor after long amounts of html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have something like this:

```
    @ if(Model.Name == "Bob")
    {
    <div>blah blah blah</div>
    <table><tr><td>blah blah blah</td></tr></table>
    }
    else
    {
    <table>
    @foreach(Something something in Model.SomethingCollection)
    {
      <div>@somthing.blah</div>
    }
<div>more html here</div>
}
```

that last closing "}" isn't being recognized as the close to my else block though and so it's causing a parser error.

I tried using @} but it doesn't like that.  How can I reenter a code block to put in that last "}"

Comment: Do you need the extra { in the line @{foreach(Something... or is that a typo in your question?

Comment: oops...I just typed that up quickly for an example.  I just edited my OP to fix it...but the problem still remains :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing @ before foreach ?

Comment: turns out I had some html markup that was borked.  When I fixed it, I indeed needed to remove the @ before the foreach.  Thanks...well played sir :)